# set value in a form builder object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have formbuilder,

```
gip: any = {
    upper: 460,
    lower: 175
};

this.demandsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    gip:[{lower: parseInt(this.gip), upper: parseInt(this.gip)}],
});
```

I am trying to set value using,

```
if (this.demands.max_gip != undefined) {
    this.demandsForm.controls['gip']['value']['upper'].setValue(this.demands.max_gip);
}
```

But I am unable to set the value.

Comment: What errors are reported to you? This: `parseInt(this.gip)` is not likely to be what you mean because parsing an Object to an int is not really a great idea.

Comment: Why are you using Object inside gip formControl intead you can create another formGroup

Comment: you have to create nested form group.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
this.demandsForm.patchValue({
      upper: this.demands.max_gip 
    });
```